# TypeError: Cannot read property 'setDefaults' in jQuery datepicker function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I implemented the code below into my html but looks like it is conflicting with something. On it own it works perfectly well but when I applied it to my html page my datepicker doesn't work properly: basically when I click on it, it doesn't give me the drop down menu to choose from. 
Here is the code that I applied in my html page.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-   ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <form action="jquery.php" method="post">
    Date:<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" />
  </form>
 </div>
 <script>
    $(function() {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "" ] );
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
         onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
    $(this).parent('form').submit();
      }
   });
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried placing the jQuery library  before the plug in >, that did nothing.
Here is the link to my html page on github. 
https://alohavolha.github.io/selene-hotel/

Comment: Why is there spaces in `jquery-   ui.css`...? What is `$.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "" ] );` supposed to do?

Comment: the spaces were added here accidentally I suppose when I was copying and pasting and adjusting the text to the correct format. The setDefaults - setting the default settings. Everything else IDK. I copied this code from somebody who posted a similar question but his code worked. @EthanEttleman actually solved this problem. but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When I changed your input type to date the date picker worked just fine here's the code: 
`<form action="jquery.php" method="post">
    Date:<input type="date" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" />
  </form>`

Comment: First of all , thank you for trying to help me here. 
well, it works and it doesn't, heh ( I wish I could screen shot it and show what it does).
Basically, when I click in the input area the "mm" shows and I have the little arrows on the right side that I can use to manage the number to go up or down. If I click a little more to the right from "mm" ( and they only show when I click in the area) I see "dd", same thing happens with "yyyy". But what I really whant to happen is the whole drop down calendar menu.

Comment: quick update: the drop down menu work BUT in order for it to show I have to click on white space on the right side close to the border. Is there any way I can make the entire box function like that? so that the menu shows if a person clicks anywhere inside the box? thank you

Comment: ok, another update :)
 so I was able to stylize the input area of the datepicker and since my backgroun-color is dark, the "mm/dd/yyyy" now shows up. Yay. 
Would you know by any chance how to stylize the drop-down calendar?

Comment: Instead of posting your thoughts as multiple answers, please [edit] the  existing answer, update it and delete the others

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, sorry for the late reply. There are various styles that you can use to customize the HTML5 date picker using HTML pseudo elements.

In HTML you can limit the min and max dates a user can select by using:

```
<input ID="datepicker" type="date" min="2016-07-31" max="2016-08-31">
```

It should be noted that all browsers that support the "date" input type will support the min and max attribute values being set, but when you forget to set one of the values your date picker will be buggy depending on the browser.

As for adding specific colors and styles with CSS you can use the following input type pseudo elements. The first shows how the syntax should be for adding properties and values.

```
::-webkit-datetime-edit {padding: 0.5em;}
::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper
::-webkit-datetime-edit-text
::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field
::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field
::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field
::-webkit-inner-spin-button
::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator
```

If you have anymore questions just let me know. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so far! I was able to even stylize it and make it look semi-decent. I was wondering if there is a better way to create the starting and final date. Ex. when you check in a hotel: you choose your starting date and checkout date.

Answer (score -2):

Also I'm 85% percent sure that you can't style the drop down portion. Each browser has default styles set for the date picker. This is also true for mobile devices. Each styles them accordingly